# Objects exported from Blender don't render properly

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I recently started learning OpenGL, I wanted to advance from the manually written cube and wanted to use models exported from Blender. The easiest way seemed to be by parsing .obj files so I made a parser.

It works but not quite well, I stumbled upon a problem when I wanted to learn about lights. The reflections and shadows weren't right at all. They made no sense in relation to where the light was. So I rendered in wireframe mode and to my surprize, there were some extra faces that weren't supposed to be there.

Screenshot: http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5937/582ff91c155b466495b2b02.png

I then generated the .obj file using the data I parsed and compared it using a diff tool to the original .obj file and nothing seems to be wrong. There are some missing zeros like 0.01 instead of 0.0100 but nothing else.

Here is my parser: http://pastebin.com/Aw8mdhJ9

Here is where I use the parsed data: pastebin.com/5Grt1WGf

And this is my toFloatBuffer:

```
public static FloatBuffer makeFloatBuffer(float[] arr) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    fb.put(arr);
    fb.position(0);
    return fb;
}
```

Comment: This is namely a guess but I think it's the rendering causing this artefact. You're rendering all faces as one long line array while the faces can be on opposite sides of the sphere. Rendering the object per face could fix this. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Thank you for the information, can you explain a bit more in detal how I can test your suggestion? I'm new to OpenGL

Comment: If, I mean if, this is the reason, you should keep the per face indices information. And render every face separately. You could start with a simpler object which has only two separate triangles. If you render it with your current code I'm suspecting that the triangles get connected with a line. If not current code changing render mode to LINE_STRIP should demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Indeed it happens as you said. But I don't know how to render it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking around the internet I found lots of different opinions. With a bit more study I figured out what was the problem. The problem was that the normals were per face and for OpenGL they need to be per vertex.

To fix this I rearranged the parsed data and made new indices. The problem is I am using more indices now and with the GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT limitation in OpenGL ES, my vertex count gets more limited.

Here is the code I used to fix the arrays:

```
private static void makeThingsWork() {
    int n_points = faces.length * 3;
    short count = 0;
    int j = 0;

    float[] fixedvertices = new float[n_points];
    float[] fixednormals = new float[n_points];
    short[] fixedfaces = new short[faces.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < n_points; i+=3)
    {
        j = i/3;
        fixedvertices[i] = vertices[faces[j]*3];
        fixedvertices[i+1] = vertices[faces[j]*3 + 1];
        fixedvertices[i+2] = vertices[faces[j]*3 + 2];

        fixednormals[i] = normals[normalIndices[j]*3];
        fixednormals[i+1] = normals[normalIndices[j]*3 + 1];
        fixednormals[i+2] = normals[normalIndices[j]*3 + 2];

        fixedfaces[i/3] = count;
        count++;
    }

    vertices = fixedvertices;
    normals = fixednormals;
    faces = fixedfaces;


}
```